# Sql Inner Join with distinct values

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

- Bank Transfer
- Beneficiaries
- Callback_Procedure

I have to join those 3 tables with an inner join.

In the Bank Transfer, I have a column `Number`, and the `Number` is repeated in the Beneficiaries and Callback table.

In the `Beneficiaries` table, the number can repeat more than once.

When running my inner join query, am getting more than 1 result instead of getting unique values.

In the `Beneficiaries` table, I also have a column `Beneficial_Name` and it is this column that uniquely identifies the result, however when running the join query, am getting duplicate results.

I have tried distinct option, not to great result.

Below is my code - can someone please help me out?

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Beneficial_Name,   
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Number, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Start_Date, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Team_Name, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Initiator, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Staff, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Process_Name, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Company_Name, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Billing_Amount, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Entry_ID, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Instructions, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.BT_Count, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Misspelled, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Sender, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Odd, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Email, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Beneficiary, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Address, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Urgent,
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Payment, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Sperry, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Contact, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Reasonable, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Evidence_Completed, dbo.Bank_Transfer.End_Date, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.First_Mgr_Approval_Name, dbo.Bank_Transfer.First_Mgr_Approval, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.First_Mgr_Approval_Date, dbo.Bank_Transfer.CallBack_Workings, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.CallBack_Agreement, dbo.Bank_Transfer.CallBack_Procedure, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Second_Mgr_Approval_Name, dbo.Bank_Transfer.Second_Mgr_Approval,
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.Second_Mgr_Approval_Date, dbo.Bank_Transfer.IB, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.IB_Date, dbo.Bank_Transfer.ITL_Signatory_Approval, 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer.ITL_Signatory_Name, 
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Account_Number, dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Currency, 
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Payment_Details, dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.CurrencyPayment, 
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Amount, dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Purpose, 
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Evidence, dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Due_Diligence, 
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.WC, dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Resolution_Directors,
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Manager_Approval, dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Mgr_Approval_Date, 
    dbo.CB_BankAccount.Number AS Expr3, dbo.CB_BankAccount.Company_Name AS Expr4, 
    dbo.CB_BankAccount.Bank_Name, dbo.CB_BankAccount.Bank_Account, 
    dbo.CB_BankAccount.Currency AS Expr5, dbo.CB_BankAccount.Balance, 
    dbo.CB_BankAccount.Bank_Mandate, dbo.CB_BankAccount.Signing_Arrangement AS Expr6,
    dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.Number AS Expr8, dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.CallStatus, 
    dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.Person_CalledBack, dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.DateTime,
    dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.Notes, dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.Mgr_Approval, 
    dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.DateTime_Approval, dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.Bank_DateTime 
FROM 
    dbo.Bank_Transfer 
INNER JOIN  
    dbo.BT_Beneficiaries ON dbo.Bank_Transfer.Number = dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Number 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CB_BankAccount ON dbo.BT_Beneficiaries.Number = dbo.CB_BankAccount.BT_Number 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure ON dbo.CB_BankAccount.BT_Number = dbo.CB_CallBack_Procedure.Number
```

Comment: What does it need to say in the Beneficial Name column for you to know the record is the one you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a WHERE clause that specifies what the Benficial_Name column needs to say to identify the unique record:

```
WHERE Beneficiaries = 'Unique Record'
```

Edit this to say whatever you need. You can put this after the joins.

Comment: Hello @kbball, when the query above is being process for particular value, since there a relationship of one-to-many between the table Bank_Transfer and Beneficiaries and Bank_Transfer with CallBack_Procedure, even though i'll specified the WHERE clause, it will still provide me duplicate result since when the innerjoin is being process the values have already being duplicated. Any other options

Comment: If you are using distinct, you won't get exact duplicates. What makes the rows different?